# Using javascript to set value of hidden field then access value from serverside c# code

Tags: c#, javascript

I am using a nested html unordered list styled as a drop down. When the a tag within the inner lists list item is clicked it trigger some javascript which is supposed to set the value of a hidden field to the text for the link that was clicked.

The javascript seems to work - I used an alert to read the value from the hidden field but then when I try to put that value in the querystring in my asp.net c# code behind - it pulls the initial value - not the javascript set value.

I guess this is because the javascript is client side not server side but has anyone any idea how i can get this working

**HTML**

```
    <div class="dropDown accomodation">
    <label for="accomodationList">Type of accomodation</label>
    <ul class="quicklinks" id="accomodationList">
        <li><a href="#" title="Quicklinks" id="accomodationSelectList">All types
     <!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->

    <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
    <ul id="sub" onclick="dropDownSelected(event,'accomodation');">
            <li><a href="#" id="val=-1$#$All types" >All types</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="val=1$#$Villa" >Villa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="val=2$#$Studio" >Studio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="val=3$#$Apartment" >Apartment</a></li>
            <li><a class="last" href="#" id="val=4$#$Rustic Properties" >Rustic Properties</a></li>

    </ul>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
        </li></ul>
    </div>

<input type="hidden" ID="accomodationAnswer" runat="server" />
```

**javascript**

```
    if(isChildOf(document.getElementById(parentList),document.getElementById(targ.id)) == true)
{           

            document.getElementById(parentLi).innerHTML = tname;            
            document.getElementById(hiddenFormFieldName).Value = targ.id;
            alert('selected id is ' + targ.id + ' value in hidden field is ' +           document.getElementById(hiddenFormFieldName).Value);
}
```

**C# code**

```
String qstr = "accom=" + getValFromLiId(accomodationAnswer.Value) + "&sleeps=" + getValFromLiId(sleepsAnswer.Value) + "&nights=" + getValFromLiId(nightsAnswer.Value) + "&region=" +
getValFromLiId(regionAnswer.Value) + "&price=" + Utilities.removeCurrencyFormatting(priceAnswer.Value);
```

Answer (score 13):

I would do this: First, remove the `runat='server'` attribute from the hidden field (inside body):

```
<input type="hidden" id="accomodationAnswer" />
```

Now, on the server, where you want to read that value, do this:

```
string accomodationAnswer = Request.Form["accomodationAnswer"];

// now use accomodationAnswer instead of accomodationAnswer.Value 
// in the C# code that you indicated you are using
```

That should do it.

Comment: This is the best solution, as Viewstate is the key item that causes the values to re-load

Comment: without the runat='server' the Request.Form["accomodationAnswer"] does not have the key accomodationAnswer. am I missing sommething else?

Answer (score 6):

Try this

if you are using .net 4.0 then in page header.

Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Page.cs" Inherits="Page"

Alongwith this write:

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

It helps in not changing the server side control id at runtime

Now

Set the value in javascript as

document.getElementById("hiddenField").value = "Vallue";

And access in codebehind like below.

string hiddenVallue=hiddenField.Value.ToString();