# Pass multiple html parameter with BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, parameters

I need to send parameters with values ​​in a BeginForm html.

Example:

```
@ using (Html.BeginForm ("Create", "IncomeDeclaration", new {declarationAmount = document.getElementById ("element"). value}))
```

This value I can not get from the Model, as it is not found in the model.
I've tried several ways and nothing worked. If you could change the content of a ViewBag that'd be great.

I appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix and match Javascript (`document.getElementById ("element")`) with the C# form declaration. If you want a value submitted with the form, you should add a relevant form element inside the form declaration. If you don't want a regular form element (eg. a textbox), you can use a "hidden" input field. If you want, you can [dynamically populate the hidden field using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331599/using-javascript-to-set-value-of-hidden-field-then-access-value-from-serverside).